# FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Encountering a Firebase error in a React application while using useEffect for user data fetching. The error message is 'Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference, or FirebaseFirestore.' The issue seems to be related to the handling of the authMethod field. It's suspected that the error arises when the user object is initially null and populates with user information after some time. Seeking guidance on resolving this error and ensuring correct user data retrieval without the 'authMethod' field in the Firebase Firestore database when the user information becomes available.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        if (user) {
          const userDocRef = doc(db, "collectionName", user.uid);
          const userDocSnapshot = await getDoc(userDocRef);
          if (userDocSnapshot.exists()) {
            const userData = userDocSnapshot.data();
            if (userData && userData.authMethod) {
              // Remove 'authMethod' field
              delete userData.authMethod;

              // Now 'userData' contains the user data without 'authMethod'
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle error
        console.error("Error fetching user data: ", error);
      } 
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [user]);
```

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from this code? As a matter of fact the error is about the `collection()` method, which is not used in your code snippet. Also, since you do `if (user) {}`,  `user.uid` should not be undefined.

Comment: The error message is talking about a call to a function called "collection", but you have no such function call here. Please edit the question to clearly indicate which line of code is causing the problem.